# I can't see library (.a) in cornerstone so I can't add it

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cornerstone

I can't see library (.a) in cornerstone so I can't add it. Ho can I make Cornerstone to see it?

Comment: You can always add it manually thru the terminal. E.g. If you're working with SVN you'd want to type `svn add libname.a`.

Comment: ok, i know but I bought visual tool to avoid command line :-) thank you anyway

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should show ignored items, by clicking on the little eye button at the bottom toolbar :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is because ".a" is in your global ignore list. You can edit the list by going into Settings->Subversion->General->Global ignores.

When you delete the ".a" from here it will no longer be ignored.